# angular-meteor: how do you $watch Collections from the `helpers` method?

Tags: angular-meteor

I am using `ng-repeat` inside a directive on a context variable set by the `helper` function, but the directive is not rendering the entire collection. As near as I can tell, it is rendering whatever it finds at the time of the directive `postLink`, but does not re-render when the Collection grows.

I tried to add a `$watch` to the directive, but it only fires once on load, even as the Collection grows.

Here is a sample I created from the `meteor-angular-socially` tutorial, see: `https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially/tree/step_14`

file: `client/parties/parties-list/parties-list.component.js`

```
angular.module('socially').directive('partiesList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'client/parties/parties-list/parties-list.html',
    controllerAs: 'partiesList',
    controller: function ($scope, $reactive) {
      $reactive(this).attach($scope);

      window.vm = vm = this;
      $scope.$watch(vm.parties, function(newV, oldV) {
        // this $watch fires once when the controller is loaded, but never again
        // but vm.parties is updated when new parties are added
        return console.warn('vm.parties.count=' + (newV != null ? newV.length : void 0));
      });

      ...

      this.helpers({
        parties: () => {
          return Parties.find({}, { sort : this.getReactively('sort') });
        },
        users: () => {
          return Meteor.users.find({});
        },
        partiesCount: () => {
          return Counts.get('numberOfParties');
        }
      });
```

The `$scope.$watch` does not fire when the Collection is updated. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

dooh! the answer is to use `scope.$watchCollection` instead of `scope.$watch`

Answer (score 0):

@michael `scope.$watchCollection` may work in some cases, but if you want to watch for all data changes you need to use deep watch: $scope.$watch(func, **true**)

```
$scope.$watch(vm.parties, function(newV, oldV) {
    return console.warn('vm.parties.count=' + (newV != null ? newV.length : void 0));
}, true);
```

Also `getReactively` may use deep watch too if you set second argument to true: `$scope.getReactively('var', true)`